# Example syslog-ng configuration to replicate rsyslog filename & locations?

Tags: centos, rsyslog, syslog-ng

ng 3.6.3 from source compilation on CentOS 6.6 64bit to play with and was wondering if anyone has pointers or example syslog-ng.conf that would as close as possible replicate the default rsyslog filenames and locations for logging. The default source tarball /usr/local/etc/syslog-ng.conf only provides the following at /usr/local/etc/syslog-ng.conf

```
# Default syslog-ng.conf file which collects all local logs into a
# single file called /var/log/messages.
#

@version: 3.6
@include "scl.conf"

source s_local {
        system();
        internal();
};

source s_network {
        udp();
};

destination d_local {
        file("/var/log/messages");
};

log {
        source(s_local);

        # uncomment this line to open port 514 to receive messages
        #source(s_network);
        destination(d_local);
};
```

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Yea, install EPEL6 and then install the syslog-ng package from that repo:

http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/syslog-ng.html